# How to combine more than two tables into a new table with auto increment id?

Tags: mysql, database, union

In my database I have three different tables. And my tables are looking similar but having different table name and like following structure:

```
Table_One
    +------+----+
    |id|JAN||FEB|
    +------+----+
    |1 |  1||  5|
    +------+----+
    |2 |  8|| 12|
    +------+----+
    |3 | 15|| 19|
    +------+----+
    |4 | 22|| 26|
    +------+----+

Table_Two
    +------+----+
    |id|JAN||FEB|
    +------+----+
    |1 |  1||  5|
    +------+----+
    |2 |  8|| 12|
    +------+----+
    |3 | 15|| 19|
    +------+----+
    |4 | 22|| 26|
    +------+----+

Table_Three
    +------+----+
    |id|JAN||FEB|
    +------+----+
    |1 |  1||  5|
    +------+----+
    |2 |  8|| 12|
    +------+----+
    |3 | 15|| 19|
    +------+----+
    |4 | 22|| 26|
    +------+----+
```

now I want to create new table by merging all three tables together and that should be looked like following structure.

```
Table_Final
        +------+----+
        |id |JAN|FEB|
        +------+----+
        |1  |  1|  5|
        +------+----+
        |2  |  8| 12|
        +------+----+
        |3  | 15| 19|
        +------+----+
        |4  | 22| 26|
        +------+----+
        |5  |  1|  5|
        +------+----+
        |6  |  8| 12|
        +------+----+
        |7  | 15| 19|
        +------+----+
        |8  | 22| 26|
        +------+----+
        |9  |  1|  5|
        +------+----+
        |10 |  8| 12|
        +------+----+
        |11 | 15| 19|
        +------+----+
        |12 | 22| 26|
        +------+----+
```

I tried several times using merging table all together by UNION operation. But the problem is, after creating new table using UNION operation, new table doesn't create an auto_increment id and for this reason, I do not get any permission to update, delete option in my new table's data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MySQL's user variables this is also possible without using a extra table 
But this query will always ensure the same id's because off the ORDER BY..

```
SELECT
   (@id := @id + 1) AS id   
 , JAN
 , FEB
FROM (

  SELECT

     JAN
   , FEB

  FROM (
    SELECT
       id 
     , JAN
     , FEB
     , 1 AS position
    FROM
     Table_One  

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT 
       id 
     , JAN
     , FEB
     , 2 AS position
    FROM
     Table_Two

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT 
       id 
     , JAN
     , FEB
     , 3 AS position
    FROM
     Table_Three

  ) AS Tables
  CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @id := 0 ) AS init_user_param
  ORDER BY 
     position ASC
   , id ASC
) AS Tables_user_param
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a table with id auto_increment

```
  CREATE TABLE `table_final` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `jan` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `feb` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ) ;
```

then populate using  a select union

```
    insert into table_final ( jan, feb)
    select jan, feb 
    from Table_One
    union 
    select jan, feb 
    from Table_Two 
    union 
    select jan, feb 
    from TTable_Three
```

Comment: @Jubayer this query won't ensure the same id's because off the missing ORDER BY.

Comment: @Jubayer what do you mean ??